# Finding string in dictionary key where the string is not exactly the key in the dict

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I'm trying to find the key when searching a dictionary list of keys. But the string is not an exact match to the dictionary keys. This is what i have so far:

```
if string in d.keys():
    print 'found'
```

I would like the key that was found.

Comment: what kind of matching are we really looking at? Is the string a substring of any of the keys or a subsequence maybe? or even an anagram?
BTW bad question.

Comment: say the key = 'abc123' and the string i'm using to search is 'bc1'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is anything better than a linear scan across d's keys.

```
print [k for k in d if string in k]
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is something your program relies on a lot, you could do this:

```
   class ApproxDict(dict):

      def __contains__(self, item):
          # item contains the key. Do what you need with it.
          return True # or False again this depends on what you want
```

Using either of the other solutions suggested to implement the `__contains__()` method.
That way you have your customized lookup and retain the readability of python.

For key substring lookup as you precised in your comment:

```
    >>> class ApproxDict(dict):
    ...     def __contains__(self, item):
    ...         for key in self.keys():
    ...             if item in key:
    ...                 return True
    ...         return False
    ... 
    >>> d = ApproxDict()
    >>> d['abc123'] = "some value"
    >>> 'bc1' in d
    True
    >>> 'bc2' in d
    False
    >>>
```

See [the python data model documentation.](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__)
Hope that helps.

By the way, with a dictionnary:

```
    if key in d:
        # whatever
```

is equivalent to:

```
    if key in d.keys():
        # whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that `distance` compares two strings and returns a lower number if the strings are a good match and a higher number when the strings are a bad match. (You have to decide what to employ there, Levenshtein, etc).

```
bestMatch = None
value = None
for k, v in d.items ():
    match = distance (k, searchedKey)
    if bestMatch == None or bestMatch > match:
         bestMatch = match
         value = v
print (value) # the value of the best matched key
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want to fuzzy string match with the keys.  Here's what I suggest:

```
>>> keys = ["apple", "plum", "pear", "carrot"]
>>> d = {key:val for key, val in zip(keys,range(4))}
>>> d
{'plum': 1, 'carrot': 3, 'pear': 2, 'apple': 0}
>>>
>>> searchKey = "aple"
>>>
>>> import difflib
>>>
>>> try:
...     searchVal = d[searchKey]
... except:
...     closeKey = difflib.get_close_matches(searchKey, d.keys(), 1)[0]
...     searchVal = d[closeKey]
...
>>> searchVal
0
```